# How to change name of array - form builder for alpaca

Tags: jquery, forms, alpacajs

I got some problems. I am doing a formBuilder for `Alpaca` Forms. And its going good, but how to change name of this `array` which got array inside or maybe i am doing this wrong. Any idea how to start building it? Is that right way ?

```
jQuery(function($) {
    var data = {
        "schema": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": []
        },
    };

    $('.modal-footer').on('click', '#qID', function(e) {
        var name = $("input#questionID").val();
        var question = $("textarea#question").val();
        console.log(data);

        var obj = {
            name: {
                "type": "string",
                "title": question
            }
        };
        data.schema.properties.push(obj);
        test = JSON.stringify(data);
        fulltest = test.replace("[", "");
        fulltest = fulltest.replace("]", "");
        console.log(fulltest);
        fulltest = JSON.parse(fulltest);
        $("#form").alpaca(fulltest);
        console.log(fulltest);
    });
});
```

And the problem is that i need to get val of name and put it to `json` at place where name: { .. is.

My current result is:

```
 {"schema":{"type":"object","properties":{"name THAT STRING NOT REPLACE WITH OBJECT NAME VALUE":{"type":"string","title":"qweqweqweq"}}}}
```

Did someone got good form builder with logic forms? conditional dependencies ? `Alpaca` support it, but I a got problem with creating the JSON for it.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-header">
        <h5 class="card-title">Dodaj formularz</h5>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="form_title">Tytuł formularza</label>
          <input type="text" name="form_title" id="form_title" class="form-control" />
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-9 col-xs-12" id="form">
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-12">
            <button id="question" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#MyModal" class="btn btn-default">Pytanie otwarte</button>
            <button id="checkbox" class="btn btn-default">Pytanie wielokrotnego wyboru</button>
            <button id="list" class="btn btn-default">Rozwijana lista odpowiedzi</button>
            <button id="grid" class="btn btn-default">Pytanie wielokrotnego wyboru (grid)</button>
            <button id="number" class="btn btn-default">Odpowiedź w postaci liczby</button>
            <button id="data" class="btn btn-default">Odpowiedź w postaci daty</button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal fade" id="MyModal" role="dialog">
          <div class="modal-dialog">

     <!-- Modal content-->
     <div class="modal-content">
       <div class="modal-header">
         <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
         <h4 class="modal-title">Settings</h4>
       </div>
       <div class="modal-body">
         <div class="form-group">
           <label for="questionID">Question ID</label>
           <input type="text" class="form-contsrol" id="questionID" placeholder="Your question ID">
         </div>
         <div class="form-group">
           <label for="question">Question</label>
           <textarea type="text" class="form-control" id="question"></textarea>
         </div>
         <div class="form-group">
           <label for="">Dependencies</label>
           <input type="text" id="dependencies" name="dependencies{this.value['choice']}" placeholder="Choice ID">
         </div>
       </div>
       <div class="modal-footer">
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-dismiss="modal" id="qID">Save</button>
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
       </div>
     </div>

   </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Can you provide any HTML?

Comment: I edited my question

Comment: My first idea, was to get for example "question open" and then opened Modal in modal are setting like, dependencies, name, question and with save that creat object and render with alpaca. I propably can saave this json in database for future use or edit.

Comment: or meybe you got another idea how to make formbuilder for alpaca,